# Adding a copyright message to images whatever size they are

Tags: asp.net

I would like help for ways to add a copyright footer on web page.aspx so that it always remains at the end no matter the size of the image.

When my image increases in size, the copyright message should still appear on it.

Comment: Post your code - It's a design flaw I guess. you used fixed location and not relative

Answer (score 0):

Do you want copyright to appear on image or your aspx page ? If you want it on your aspx page, just wrap it inside a div and place it in your master page in the end.

If you want it on an image in your aspx page your should consider water marking it instead.